# Table-per-hierarchy table has missing columns for sub-types

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, .net-5, asp.net5

I have an issue where the database table created for the super-type `VeganItem` does not have the `RecipeItem` sub-type columns: `servesCount`, `cookTime`, `prepTime`, `method`, `tips`, `ingredients` in it when using Table Per Hierarchy in EF Core.

The super-type:

```
[Serializable]
public abstract class VeganItem : DomainEntity<int>
{
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int IsNotVeganCount { get; set; } = 0;
    [Required]
    public int IsVeganCount { get; set; } = 0;
    [Required]
    public int RatingsCount { get; set; } = 0;
    [Required]
    public int Rating { get; set; }
    public List<Option> Tags { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(10)]
    public List<String> Images { get; set; }
}

public abstract class VeganItem<TVeganItemEstablishment> : VeganItem 
    where TVeganItemEstablishment : VeganItemEstablishment
{
    [PropertyName("veganItemEstablishments", Ignore = true)]
    public virtual ICollection<TVeganItemEstablishment> VeganItemEstablishments { get; set; }
}
```

The sub-type:

```
[ElasticsearchType(RelationName = "recipeitem", IdProperty = "Id")]
public class RecipeItem : VeganItem<RecipeItemEstablishment>
{
    [Required]
    public int servesCount;
    [Required]
    public TimeSpan cookTime;
    [Required]
    public TimeSpan prepTime;
    [Required]
    public Option difficulty;
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(100)]
    public List<string> method;
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(2)]
    public List<string> tips;
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(100)]
    public List<string> ingredients;
}
```

The model builder:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<RecipeItem>(veganItem =>
{
    veganItem.Property(e => e.difficulty)
        .HasConversion(
            v => JsonSerializer.Serialize(v, null),
            v => JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Option>(v, null)
        );
});

modelBuilder.Entity<VeganItem>(veganItem =>
{
    veganItem.HasIndex("CompanyName", "Name", "Discriminator").IsUnique();
    veganItem.HasDiscriminator<string>("Discriminator");
    veganItem.Property(u => u.CreatedDate)
        .HasDefaultValueSql("CURRENT_TIMESTAMP"); 
    veganItem.Property(u => u.UpdatedDate)
        .HasDefaultValueSql("CURRENT_TIMESTAMP"); 
    veganItem.HasKey(e => e.Id);
    veganItem.HasOne(q => q.UpdatedBy)
        .WithMany()
        .HasForeignKey(k => k.UpdatedById);
    veganItem.HasOne(q => q.CreatedBy)
        .WithMany()
        .HasForeignKey(k => k.CreatedById);
    veganItem.Property(e => e.Tags)
        .HasConversion(
            v => JsonSerializer.Serialize(v, null),
            v => JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<Option>>(v, null)
        );
});

public DbSet<VeganItem> VeganItems { get; set; }     
public DbSet<RecipeItem> RecipeItems { get; set; }
```

It creates a column for `difficulty`. I suppose because that property has a value converter in the data context.

Any idea how to get the fields mentioned at the top of the question to appear in the database table?

**EDIT: This made it work - I just didn't think it was necessary**

```
modelBuilder.Entity<RecipeItem>(veganItem =>
{
    veganItem.Property(e => e.Difficulty)
        .HasConversion(
            v => JsonSerializer.Serialize(v, null),
            v => JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Option>(v, null)
        );

    veganItem.Property(e => e.Tips);
    veganItem.Property(e => e.ServesCount);
    veganItem.Property(e => e.CookTime);
    veganItem.Property(e => e.PrepTime);
    veganItem.Property(e => e.Method);
    veganItem.Property(e => e.Ingredients);
});
```

Comment: All these are **fields** - make them **properties**.

Comment: @IvanStoev ahhhhh okay perfect thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Entity Framework does not support collections of primitive types. You can either create an entity (which will be saved to a different table) or do some string processing to save your list as a string and populate the list after the entity is materialized.

- you have created all the columns as fields. Not properties. (make them properties) i.e

  public TypeName propName {get;set;}

and then run the migration or command.

Comment: For PostgreSql it does, which is apparently used here. Also please note that there's no issue anymore. The question should either be closed, deleted or self-answered.